# Problem transferring a json string from the client to the esp8266 server

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, arduino-esp8266

As part of my WLAN Thermometer project, I am planning a small file management for the files stored on the ESP. In this context, I need to transfer a list of file names from the client to the server. Because there is also the wonderful ArduinoJSON library for the ESP 8266, I would like to pass the data as a JSON object. The first excerpt from the scripts.js of my webpage shows how to create the `filelist` (contains all available files at ESP Filesystem) and compile and transfer the `deletelist` (whose elements should be deleted).

```
let fileID = 0
for (i = 2; i < FDatas.length; i += 2) 
{
   let fileInfo = {
      name: FDatas[i], 
      size: FDatas[i+1], 
      fileID: fileID, 
      marked: false};
      fileList.push(fileInfo);
   };
}

function deleteFiles() {

   let deleteFileList = [];
   let fileID = 0;

   for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      if (fileList[i].marked == true) {
          let keyname = 'fileID_' + String(fileID);
          fileID += 1;

          let newEntry = {[keyname]:fileList[i].name}

          deleteFileList.push(newEntry);
      }
   }

   if (deleteFileList.length > 0) {
    
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       var formData = JSON.stringify(deleteFileList);
       xhttp.open("POST", "/deleteFiles");
       xhttp.send(formData);
    }
 }
```

On the server side, communication is organized as follows:
In the setup part of the arduino code:

```
  webserver.on("/deleteFiles", HTTP_POST, deleteFiles);
```

In the handler:

```
  void deleteFiles() {
     String input = webserver.arg("plain");
     Serial println(input);

     DynamicJsonDocument doc(2048);

     DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(doc, input);

     if (err) {
        Serial.println(F("deserializeJson() failed with code "));
        Serial.println(err.f_str());
     }

     JsonObject obj = doc.as<JsonObject>();

     // Loop through all the key-value pairs in obj
     for (JsonPair p : obj) {
        Serial.println(p.key().c_str());
        if (p.value().is<const char*>()) {
           auto s = p.value().as<const char*>();
           Serial.println(s);
        }
     }
     webserver.send(200);
  }
```

The result of these efforts is sobering. Nevertheless, the `Serial.println(input);` - command outputs the following,

```
 [{"fileID_0":"/settings.json"},{"fileID_1":"/tdata.js"},{"fileID_2":"/scripts.js"}]
```

the passage through the JSON object does not result in key value pairs.

Where is my mistake? Thank you very much for your good advice.

**1. Udate:**

After first comment (Thank You) I've changed the arduino-code to:

```
void deleteFiles() {
   String input = webserver.arg("plain");

   Serial.println(input);

   DynamicJsonDocument doc(2048);

   DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(doc, input);

   if (err) {
      Serial.println(F("deserializeJson() failed with code "));
      Serial.println(err.f_str());
   }

   JsonArray arr = doc.to<JsonArray>();

   for(JsonVariant v : arr) {
      Serial.println(v.as<const char*>());
   }
   webserver.send(200);
}
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same. No result in the loop.

Comment: the json string is a json array, not a json object

Comment: items in that array are json objects

Comment: but if I check the arr-length, then the result is zero! Even if the ckeck arr.isNull gives a 0, what means false, what means the array is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your json object consists of an array(each element of an array is indexed by a number like 0, 1, 2...), and within the array, there are these 3 json objects. So to access the data of each array element, you do `doc[0]` and so on. You can then access each key value pair with `doc[0]['key']` notation.

```
StaticJsonDocument<192> doc;

DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, input);

if (error) {
  Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
  Serial.println(error.f_str());
  return;
}

const char* element1 = doc[0]["fileID_0"]; // "/settings.json"

const char* element2 = doc[1]["fileID_1"]; // "/tdata.js"

const char* element3 = doc[2]["fileID_2"]; // "/scripts.js"
```